# How to integrate Laravel 5.7 and Cassandra 3.6?

Tags: laravel, cassandra

I want to use Cassandra as my noSql database in Laravel 5.7 project. 
I've found some packages for integrate Cassandra and Laravel, but some of them is outdated.

In this git : https://github.com/ShahinSorkh/laravel-cassandra , 
it said that we must have datastax php and it only works with php version 5.6.*, 7.0.* and 7.1.*.

My php version is 7.2

Anyone can recommend packages for integrate Laravel and Cassandra that support Laravel 5.7 and php 7.2 or How to integrate it ?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no other cassandra php driver (unfortunately!)

However, you could manually compile that driver using [this guide](https://github.com/datastax/php-driver/blob/master/ext/README.md#manually-build-and-install-2). This requires that the c++ driver is also installed which is described on top of the page. Summarized the steps for compiling PHP extension are:

```
git clone https://github.com/datastax/php-driver.git
pushd ext
phpize
popd
mkdir build
pushd build
../ext/configure
make
make install
popd
```

**Important note**: If you need to compile this for 7.4 and above and this throws some errors containing "ulong not defined", you need to apply the changes in [this PR](https://github.com/datastax/php-driver/pull/143).

**UPDATE 09/2020**: I'm currently working on refactoring my app to get rid of cassandra. Cassandra Libs, especially for PHP, are not well maintained and [C++ & PHP drivers are being abandonded by DataStax](https://github.com/datastax/php-driver/pull/143#issuecomment-650208915)